# REGEX in Snowflake/SQL for Serialized Ruby Hash values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

This is a tough one (for me at least). I need to obtain the words after "host_goal_to_have" and "host_goal_to_be_able" and there's not really a strong pattern to signify the end.

For example, the result for "host_goal_to_have" should be: "established a thriving community of actors supporting each other and turning passion into income!". And for "host_goal_to_be_able" being: "reach people and unlock the artist inside them"

Sample:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
signup_recaptcha: 
hide_welcome_checklist: true
seen_spaces_migration_welcome_intro: true
host_goal_to_have: established a thriving community of actors supporting each other
  and turning passion into income!
host_goals_updated_at: '2023-02-11T23:00:52.441Z'
host_goal_to_be_able: reach people and unlock the artist inside them
seen_event_form: true
```

Comment: Are the line breaks preserved?

Comment: Surely there is a strong pattern to signify the end - it’s the next “key value”, isn’t it? For example, “host_goal_to_be_able” ends when you get to “seen_event_form”

Answer (score 0):

So we can start with the same data:

```
with data as (
    select * from values 
    ($$--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
signup_recaptcha: 
hide_welcome_checklist: true
seen_spaces_migration_welcome_intro: true
host_goal_to_have: established a thriving community of actors supporting each other
  and turning passion into income!
host_goals_updated_at: '2023-02-11T23:00:52.441Z'
host_goal_to_be_able: reach people and unlock the artist inside them
seen_event_form: true$$)
)
```

and then we can split it into lines, find the matching "start of line tokens `[a-z_]:` and assume these are not embedded into a values section. Then separate `token: value` from `value`

```
select d.column1
    ,s.*
    ,RLIKE(s.value, '^[a-z_]+:.*$') as r1
    ,regexp_substr(s.value, '^[a-z_]+:(.*)$', 1,1,'c',1) as r2
    ,iff(r1, r2, s.value) as ss
from data as d,
    table(split_to_table(d.column1, '\n')) as s
```

after this we can chain the values back together:

```
with data as (
    select * from values 
    ($$--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
signup_recaptcha: 
hide_welcome_checklist: true
seen_spaces_migration_welcome_intro: true
host_goal_to_have: established a thriving community of actors supporting each other
  and turning passion into income!
host_goals_updated_at: '2023-02-11T23:00:52.441Z'
host_goal_to_be_able: reach people and unlock the artist inside them
seen_event_form: true$$)
), pass_1 as (
    select d.column1
        ,s.seq
        ,s.index
        ,regexp_substr(s.value, '^[a-z_]+:') as t
        ,nvl(t, lag(t)ignore nulls over(partition by s.seq order by s.index)) as token
        ,iff(RLIKE(s.value, '^[a-z_]+:.*$'), regexp_substr(s.value, '^[a-z_]+:(.*)$', 1,1,'c',1), s.value) as ss
    from data as d,
        table(split_to_table(d.column1, '\n')) as s
)
select  
    seq, 
    token, 
    listagg(ss) within group (order by index) as val
from pass_1
where token is not null
group by 1,2
;
```

which gives:

| SEQ | TOKEN | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | seen_spaces_migration_welcome_intro: | true |
| 1 | host_goals_updated_at: | '2023-02-11T23:00:52.441Z' |
| 1 | signup_recaptcha: |  |
| 1 | host_goal_to_have: | established a thriving community of actors supporting each other and turning passion into income! |
| 1 | host_goal_to_be_able: | reach people and unlock the artist inside them |
| 1 | hide_welcome_checklist: | true |
| 1 | seen_event_form: | true |

which can be filter via HAVING:

```
select  
    seq, 
    token, 
    trim(listagg(ss) within group (order by index)) as val
from pass_1
where token is not null
group by 1,2
having token in ('host_goal_to_have:', 'host_goal_to_be_able:')
```

| SEQ | TOKEN | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | host_goal_to_have: | established a thriving community of actors supporting each other and turning passion into income! |
| 1 | host_goal_to_be_able: | reach people and unlock the artist inside them |